# How can I add a dragged item to an array once it has been dropped to the drop target in JavaScript and then display it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, drag-and-drop

I want to get the data from each dragged item once it has been dropped and add it to an array. I am relatively new to Javascript so I'm unsure how I can achieve this. I want 'data' added to the 'total' array each time an item is dropped, this is what I have so far:

```
function dropHandler(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  const totalBalance = [];
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var dropTarget = document.getElementById('drop-target');
  
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  
  // changes colour of drop target when dragged over
  ev.currentTarget.style.background = "black";
  
  totalText = document.getElementById('totalText');
  totalText.innerHTML = totalBalance
}
```

Comment: `totalBalance.push(data);` to add it into the list if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, but I assume I would need to use a loop otherwise the array is replaced with the last dropped item. Not entirely sure how to go about it though. thanks.

Comment: You can move the `totalBalance` list definition to be before the `dropHandler()` function, this way it is not redefined every time something is dropped - if you are unsure about how to do this let me know and I can post an answer below with a code example.

Comment: That was what I was after, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you got it solved! I have posted an answer below for anyone else that may stumble upon this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

With the list you have created, you can simply just push new values into it with `push(value)`, this inserts the given value into the list.

```js
let totalBalance = []; // Table to track all of the balances.

function dropHandler(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var dropTarget = document.getElementById('drop-target');
  
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  
  // changes colour of drop target when dragged over
  ev.currentTarget.style.background = "black";

  // Insert this data into our total balance's list.
  totalBalance.push(data);
  
  totalText = document.getElementById('totalText');
  totalText.innerHTML = totalBalance
}
```

The `totalBalance` list is defined before the function definition so it is not overwritten every time something is dropped.